# Convert Json file into GraphJSON to be imported into Titan

Tags: json, titan, tinkerpop

I have been looking at ways to convert a JSON file into a GraphJSON graph and I have come across the [GraphJSON Reader and Writer Library](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/GraphSON-Reader-and-Writer-Library).

However, what I do not really understand is whether I can read out directly from a path where a JSON file resides and parse it into a graph/GraphJSON.

Can you help?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. The GraphSON reader/writer library will not help you convert anything, it expects a particular format.

Comment: It is expecting a GraphSON format, it seems (this was my original doubt), so I need an external conversion script to 'graphitise' my JSON file.

Comment: Note that you might be looking at very old documentation of GraphSON depending on the version of TinkerPop you are using. Those docs point at 2.x which is no longer under development. See 3.x docs for GraphSON [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.1.1-incubating/reference/#graphson-reader-writer)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would solve this issue:

1. Read your JSON files using GSON or Jackson, then
2. Feed this data into a subclass of [Vertex](https://github.com/apache/incubator-tinkerpop/blob/master/gremlin-core/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/Vertex.java)/[Edge](https://github.com/apache/incubator-tinkerpop/blob/master/gremlin-core/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/Edge.java)  of your implementation of these Tinkerpop 3 interfaces.
3. Use the GraphSON writer [methods](https://github.com/apache/incubator-tinkerpop/blob/34309809e03332196474c510ea8175c9327ad835/gremlin-core/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/io/graphson/GraphSONWriter.java) to "graphitise" your data, save your data into an OutputStream.

I'm assuming you're using Tinkerpop3 and Titan 1.0.0, [this](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#graphson-reader-writer)  is the right documentation.

Good luck!

P.S: If you're doing this for the sack of importing data into Titan, you might be overcomplicating the issue of data import. Just import it straight away.